# Sending Data to Browser Using Cgi in C++ Without cout

Tags: c++, c, cgi, cout

I have 100,000 or more records ( 50 Fields per )Record in my Flat File. My code will read the entire file and load it into a Vector STL Container. I want to send this entire data as a JavaScript Array format to browser using Cgi. For loading it into memory , Its not taking much more time. But When I'm printing the whole data using 'Cout' or 'printf' statement It takes much more time. Is there any option to send the data to browser without using 'cout' or 'printf' as quick as fast?

Answer (score 0):

CGI interface is inherently meant to use `cout` (i.e. standard output) to render the results.

You can certainly use block write methods like [`cout.write()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write), [`fwrite(STDOUT,...)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) or `write(0,...)` instead, with pre-rendered output from e.g. a `std::string` or `std::ostringstream`. But I doubt you'll get a really significant performance gain.